# Strange Result of TypeScript `extends` Operator (Testing Types Assignability)

Tags: typescript

I'm playing around with https://2ality.com/2020/06/computing-with-types.html#conditional-types to learn the type relationships in TypeScript.

Having defined the type function `IsAssignableTo`:

```js
type IsAssignableTo<A, B> = A extends B ? true : false
```

I got the desired results like:

```js
type MyGoodType1 = IsAssignableTo<42, Object>           // MyGoodType1 === true
type MyGoodType2 = IsAssignableTo<42, object>           // MyGoodType2 === false
type MyGoodType3 = IsAssignableTo<'foo', 'foo'|'bar'>   // MyGoodType3 === true
```

However, the result of reversing the parameters of the last expression:

```js
type MyStrangeType = IsAssignableTo<'foo'|'bar', 'foo'> // MyStrangeType === boolean ???
```

is, to my surprise, neither literal `true` nor literal `false` (expecting it to be `false`), but a `boolean`?

My Questions are

1. How assignability for union types works in TS?  I've read [SPEC's Assignment Compatibility](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/doc/spec-ARCHIVED.md#3114-assignment-compatibility) and got no luck.
2. How could the result of `T1 extends T2 ? A : B` become a union of `A` and `B`?

[Complete Code in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgzgQTnAlgcwHYEMBGAbCAFQHsAeBAGigCEA%20KAXigSggA9gIMATOGqAPxRgAJwCu0AFxQAZljxwIAWABQq0JCgBZEAHFixboXAQAjI1iJk6bPiJkALACYqAeRwArCAGNg9KAGBQQD0wdp6BkYm5gyxwuLKKhrQOvqGxpBOFvBIqJi4BCSkzlTEnj5%20QVUBoeFpUZmMcXIKicl1kRkQAMzZVnm2hWQA5DIGw1Sj4wA%20wzhYIsP%20ULWpnSa9sUyiEqrqJuEAyqJYGGhEB0w51vl2RVPEw7Pzi5Njj-SrIMcip%20ddTSYOAMBFOggEAlUQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional types acting on generic arguments become distributive when given union types, i.e.,

```
IsAssignableTo<'foo' | 'bar', 'foo'> 
    = IsAssignableTo<'foo', 'foo'> | IsAssignableTo<'bar', 'foo'>
    = true | false
    = boolean
```

You can avoid that by wrapping your generic type into a one-tuple. Since the conditional is now no longer applied to a union, no distribution occurs:

```
type IsAssignableTo<A, B> = [A] extends [B] ? true : false;
```

You can also find this information in the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).